# Program for spelling out integer number digits: (in switch statement) does not match case values, why?

Tags: c, char, switch-statement

From the book "Programming in C"

> Write a program that takes an integer keyed in from the terminal and extracts and displays each digit of the integer in English. So, if the user types in 932, the program should display
>
> ```
> nine three two
> ```
>
> Remember to display “zero” if the user types in just a `0`.

Its been hours and its still cant be solved.. Do anyone know how to? This is the code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int right_digit,number;

int main ()
{    
    scanf("%i",&number);

    right_digit = number % 10;
    
    switch (right_digit)
    {
        case '0':
            printf("0");
            break;
        case '1':
            printf("one");
            break;
        case '2':
            printf("two");
            break;
        case '3':
            printf("three");
            break;
        case '4':
            printf("four");
            break;
        case '5':
            printf("five");
            break;
        case '6':
            printf("six");
            break;
        case '7':
            printf("seven");
            break;
        case '8':
            printf("eight");
            break;
        case '9':
            printf("nine");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    number = number / 10;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first problem here is, you're (*wrongly*) trying to use the character representation of the integer numbers. In your code, `right_digit` is supposed to represent an *integer* digit, not a character literal.

You must not to use the `''`s, just write

```
 case 0:

 ... 

 case 1:
```

and so on.

Just to add a bit on your mistake, it was considering the corresponding integer values of the character literal `'0'`, `'1'` and so on. [For ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), they are equivalent to

```
 case 48:
 case 49:
 .
 .
```

which is not what you intended.

That said,

- You need to put the modulo calculation and switch-case inside a loop and carry out the conversion for *all* the digits of the input integer.
- You need to start printing from the beginning (MSB), currently , you're printing from LSB. (*Hint: Start printing the result of the modulo operation*)
- `printf("0");` should be `printf("Zero ");`, as per the requirement.

Comment: Nitpick: "You don't need to" -> "You must not" ;-)

Comment: @Olaf Yes, Indeed, updated. I considered that the effort for putting `''`s are _extra_ , so the _need_ part came. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: yes, it's the same like poting images of text: I always wonder why they take the larger effort to mess it up.

Comment: Anyone know whats MSB / LSB?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Thank

Answer (score 0):

```
  /*USING SWITCH CASE ...ALSO YOU CAN USE '0' and negative numbers */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main (void)
    {
        int rem,num,sum=0,rem1,num1,add;
        printf("enter the number:\n");
        scanf("%i",&num);
        if(num<0)
        {
            printf("minus ");
            num=-num;
        }
        if(num==0)
        {
            printf("zero");
        }
        while(num!=0)
        {
           rem=num%10;
           num=num/10;
           sum=sum*10 +rem;
        }
        /*printf("%i\n",sum);*/

        while(sum!=0)
        {
            rem1=sum%10;
            sum=sum/10;
            switch(rem1)
            {
            case 0:
                printf("zero ");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("one ");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("two ");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("three ");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("four ");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("five ");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("six ");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("seven ");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("eight ");
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("nine ");
                break;
            default:
                printf("invalid no");
            }
        }
       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves the issue of reading digits left to right, and why the switch loop did not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Program to type numbers into English

int main(void)
{
    int n,d;

printf("\n\nGo ahead and type numbers:\n");
scanf("%i",&n);

while(n != 0)
{   
    
    d = (n / 100) % 100;

    
        switch(d)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("Zero ");
                break;

            case 1:
                printf("One ");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Two ");
                break;

            case 3: 
                printf("Three ");
                break;

            default:
                printf("%i   ",d);
                break;
        }

    n -= d*100;
    
        d = (n / 10) % 10;

    
        switch(d)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("Zero ");
                break;

            case 1:
                printf("One ");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Two ");
                break;

            case 3: 
                printf("Three ");
                break;

            default:
                printf("%i   ",d);
                break;
        }

    n -= d*10;

    d = n % 10;

    
        switch(d)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("Zero ");
                break;

            case 1:
                printf("One ");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Two ");
                break;

            case 3: 
                printf("Three ");
                break;

            default:
                printf("%i   ",d);
                break;
        }

    n /= 10;
    }
}
```

Here `case 0:`and `case 1:` have no `''`, since they are not characters, but numbers. Here the output would be:

`User input:`
321

`Output:`
three two one

Now,

```
d = (n / 100) % 10;
```

Gets the left digit.

```
d = (321 / 100) % 10;
d = 3 % 10;
d = 3;
```

Now,

```
 n -= d * 100;
```

Becomes:

```
n = 321 - (3 * 100);
n = 321 - 300;
n = 21;
```

The new number is 21!
Here:

```
d = (n / 10) % 10;
d = (21 / 10) % 10;
d = 2 % 10;
d = 2;
```

Then,

```
n -= d * 10;
```

Becomes:

```
n = 21 - (2 * 10);
n = 21 - 20;
n = 1;
```

The next line:

```
d = n % 10;
d = 1 % 10;
d = 1;
```

Finally,

```
n /= 10;
```

sets n to 0, canceling the loop.

Of course, you can add more cases for all the numbers!

Answer (score -2):

Hope this program will help you to understand the logic and I am also posting the solution for same problem using switch case....

```
/* Write a program that takes an integer keyed in from
 * the terminal and extracts and displays each digit of the
 * integer in English. So, if the user types in 932, the
 * program should display    >>> nine three two <<<. 
 * (Remember to display “zero” if the user types in
 * just a 0.)
 */


/*USING IF-ELSE IF*/
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main (void)
    {
        int rem,num,sum=0,rem1;
        printf("enter the number:\n");
        scanf("%i",&num);
        if(num<0)
        {
            printf("minus ");
            num=-num;
        }
        if(num==0)
        {
            printf("zero");
        }
        while(num!=0)
        {
           rem=num%10;
           num=num/10;
           sum=sum*10 +rem;
        }
        /*printf("%i\n",sum);*/

        while(sum!=0)
        {
            rem1=sum%10;
            sum=sum/10;
            if(rem1==0)
           {
             printf("zero ");
           }
            else if(rem1==1)
            {
                printf("one ");
            }
             else if(rem1==2)
            {
                 printf("two ");
            }
             else if(rem1==3)
            {
                printf("three ");
            }
             else if(rem1==4)
            {
                printf("four ");
            }
             else if(rem1==5)
            {
                printf("five ");
            }
             else if(rem1==6)
            {
                printf("six ");
            }
             else if(rem1==7)
            {
                printf("seven ");
            }
             else if(rem1==8)
            {
                printf("eight ");
            }
             else if(rem1==9)
            {
                printf("nine ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("invalid no");
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```